# xmlHttpRequest does not close connections

Tags: javascript, ajax, linux

I make an AJAX request and depending on the answer I will refresh the current page, code is like this:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
  var res = xhttp.responseText;
  if (res.length > 0) {
      window.location = res;
  }
}
}
xhttp.open("POST", "getlink.php", true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhttp.send('id='+id);
```

However I noticed that connections are not closed on the server. When running this command:

```
netstat -anl | grep 80 | awk '/^tcp/ {t[$NF]++}END{for(state in t){print state, t[state]} }'
```

I see a lot of connections in TIME_WAIT state:

```
LAST_ACK 4
LISTEN 2
SYN_RECV 2
ESTABLISHED 1421
FIN_WAIT1 9
FIN_WAIT2 17
TIME_WAIT 2250
```

It would seem that xmlHttpRequest does not close connections creating a lot of problems on the server.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not a bug, it's a feature!

It is called [Connection keep-alive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection) and is a feature of the HTTP protocol and applies to all HTTP connections, not just ones created by XMLHttpRequest.

So basically the idea is that opening a TCP connection is a complicated thing, because you need to do the costly three-way-handshake to establish a connection and allocate system resources. However most web pages load many resources at a time. It is one request for each image and one for each CSS file and so on and so on. To speed up loading and reduce server load HTTP allows that the connection to the server is kept open and is reused for subsequent requests.

The behaviour is controlled using headers from the server that specify how many connections the client should open at max and after how many seconds of idle time the connection should be closed. If you find that you have problems on the server with too many connections you should adjust these headers which can usually be configured in your web servers config files.

Comment: Excelent! Thank you! Do you have any idea what settings I should modify on a nginx/php5fpm configuration ?

Comment: See the keepalive_disable, keepalive_requests and keepalive_timeout directives: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#keepalive_disable However also note that nginx is one of the most capable server if it comes to handling huge numbers of concurrent connections, so check that this is really your problem...

Comment: I managed to bring the number of TIME_OUT connections down by tweaking some sysctl settings. My server had some very bad default values: net.ipv4.tcp_max_tw_buckets was only 8192 and net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse was 0 (tcp sockets were not reused). After changing them server connectivity has improved! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!